# Como poder agregar mas datos a mi lista de arreglos?

Tags: c#, json, lista

espero me puedan ayudar. Estoy consumiendo un api la cual se programó para traer registros con un datapicker, seleccionando un rango de fechas me trae los datos de las personas que realizaron una compra, pero el detalle es que solo me trae los últimos 15 registros, lo cual son 97 registros(por un ejemplo) lo que me deben de salir, alguien sabe como puedo traer todos los registros?¿

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta coloco los requerimiento para poder consumir el api, que son el AppKey, AppToken, el tipo de formato, etc.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aqui es donde caen los registros en mi lista, pero como lo comente al principio, solo me trae los último 15 y no los 97 que deben ser.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Anexo mi respuesta de que solo me trae 15 en mi lista y no los 97.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Veo que esta paginado, lo cual necesitas consumir varias veces la api pera especificando el numero de pagina que quieres consultar. Por lo que se puede ver solo consultas la info de la primera pagina, la cual son solo 15 datos, que es el valor por defecto de datos por pagina. Intenta consultar la pagina 2 y te traerá los 15 valores siguientes.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mi problema es que solo me trae una sola pagina, que son los 15 registros que me salen en mi lista y yo quiero traer los 97 en mi lista, alguna sugerencia para poder hacer eso'¿

Comment: La foto misma te lo está diciendo que colgaste cada página contiene 15 elementos y hay 7 páginas actualmente estas en la 1. 7*15= 105, en la última hay 8 menos que en las otras, por lo tanto, 97 elementos. Por lo que te interesa saber es como cambiar de pagina

Comment: Si, exacto! Eso es lo que eh estado comentando desde el principio, pido ayuda de como poder recorrer las demas paginas y no solo la primera, para asi poder tener todos los registros.

Comment: @Hectorepg sin conocer el api es imposible saberlo. Mira en los parámetros de ese servicio, tendrá que haber uno que indique el número de página que estás consultando. O incluso uno para indicar el tamaño por página. Luego haces un bucle for por cada página y te los vas descargando.